# Chromium error: Service is unavailable

Tags: chromium, error-handling

Everytime I try to log in using the sign in icon (above the search bar in the right corner) it tells me the service is unavailable after entering my information. Any ideas? I have tried re-installing chromium to no avail. I have read that re-installing it will help but it doesn't help. I have also tried deleting my cache and history but also to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: Re-installing seldom solves such issues. Deleting the user profile might. Anyway there's lot of info on Google you should have researched if and if you did you should have mentioned it and the results.

Comment: Goodpoint, I did do my research and I will edit the question to make it more clear

Comment: Same problem here... Google recommends to disconnect & restart - unfortunately if you disconnect you will not be able to reconnect. Same issue independently if I have 2-way verification or not...